# Regex to extract keyword from tweet

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match 'apple' in tweet data from Twitter. I want to be able to match it to hashtags too, so a match for 'apple' would be either: 'apple' or '#apple'.

Edit: An example tweet might be:

> "Today I am going to eat an apple"

or

> "Today I am going to eat an #apple"

I do NOT want to match:

> "Today I am going to eat lots of
>   apples"

I managed to match hashtags using the following `\s#([^ ]*)`, how would I make the hashtag optional?

Eventually I need to create two variations, one for case sensitive and one for case insensitive.

Comment: some examples might help non twitters :)

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the hash optional by appending a question mark:

```
\s#?([^ ]*)
```

Answer (score 2):

To match `apple` but not `apples` insert a word boundary at the end:

```
#?apple\b
```

Answer (score 0):

As the hashtag is optional, you might also need to precede "apple" with a word boundary:

```
#?\bapple\b
```